# Filling a plane with random points

Tags: c, random

I would like to fill a plane with randomly placed points, check whether any of them overlap (and if they do, move one of them to empty place) and then calculate the average distance between them. Later I plan on extending that to 3D so that it is kind of having particles in a box.
I know there must be better ways of doing it but here's what I came up with. For placing random points in a plane:

```
int pos[NUMBER][2];    /* Creates an array of NUMBER amount of points with x and y coordinate */
int a, b;
srand( time(NULL) );
for(a=0;a<NUMBER;a++)
      for(b=0;b<2;b++)
         pos[a][b]=rand()%11; /* Using modulus is random enough for now */
```

The next stage is finding points that over lap:

```
    for(a=0;a<NUMBER-1;a++)
      for(b=a+1;b<NUMBER;b++)
        if( pos[a][0] == pos[b][0] && pos[a][1] == pos[b][1])
           printf("These points overlap:\t", pos[a][0], pos[a][1]);
```

Now when I identify which points overlap I have to move one of them, but when I do the point in new position might overlap with one of the earlier ones. Is there any accepted way of solving this problem? One way is infinite while(true) loop with breaking condition but that seems very inefficient especially when system gets dense.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about “accepted” ways but I think I could offer a solution in O(`NUMER*log(GRID_SIZE)`) time, where `GRID_SIZE` is the total number of possible positions. Probably slower for small but faster for large parameters.

Comment: Why not check for overlap already when placing the points? You would need some kind of data structure to make this reasonably effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sketch of a solution that I think could work:

1. Your point generation algorithm is good, can be left as is.
2. The correct time to check for overlap is already when the point is generated. We simply generate new points until we generate one that doesn't overlap with any previous.
3. To quickly find overlap, use a hash table such as the one from '''glib'''. The key could be two int32_t packed into a int64_t union:

   `typedef union _Point {
     struct {
        int32_t x;
        int32_t y;
      };
      int64_t hashkey;
    } Point;`
4. Use the "iterate over all keys" functionality of your hash table to build the output array.

I haven't been able to test this but it should work. This assumes that the plane is large in relation to the number of points, so that overlaps are less likely. If the opposite is true, you can invert the logic: start with a full plane and add holes randomly.

Average complexity of this algorithm is O(n).

Comment: a) Checking for fullness is trivial since we know the number of points and of places on the grid. Bailing out is stupid in any case.

Comment: b) Even a board more than half full should never occur. At that point it's faster to choose places that *don't* contain points. (Which works exactly the same.)

Comment: c) Since bailing out due to the second point being placed on the first repeatedly should be frowned upon, your algorithm would not be guaranteed to terminate. (Which is admittedly unlikely.) Making the worst case a lot worse. Avg. looks good, though.

Comment: @Hermann, you are correct and I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: And taking your (b) into the solution, non-termination should be very unlikely. For a suitable choice of random function, it should eventually generate all possible outputs.

Comment: Yes, it should, but I felt the need to add that for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Of course, I don't know how come I didn't think about checking whether 'particle' is in available place or not upon creating it. Helps a lot.
Considering my background is chemistry I have no idea about complexities of algorithms, O(n) etc. so I will have to do some research into that.
Thank you to both of you!

Comment: For arrays with a fractional density of more than 1/64, it uses more space than just having an array of bits to track if a coordinate is already used or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you hinted that it should work for high densities as well, the best course of action is to create a 2D array of booleans (or bit vectors if you want to save space), where all elements are set to false initially. Then you loop NUMBER times, generating a random coordinate, and check whether the value in the array is true or not. If true, you generate another random coordinate. If false, you add the coordinate to the list, and set the corresponding element in the array to true.

The above assumes you want *exactly* NUMBER points, and a completely uniform chance of placing them. If either of those constraints are not necessary, there are other algorithms possible that use much less memory.

Comment: This assumes a quite low bound on the maximum size of coordinates, and doesn't work for real coordinates (not a requirement in the question, but a reasonable extension of the problem).

Comment: The idea was to extend it to real coordinates, yes.
In any case it's getting too complicated for me, I appreciate all the answers though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to place points at random, see if they overlap, and re-try on overlap. To avoid testing every point, you need to set up an index by space - if you have a 100*100 plane and a cut-off of 3-4, you could use 10*10 grid squares. Then you have to search four grid squares to check you don't have a hit.

But there are other ways of doing it. Uniformly placing points on a  gird will create a Poisson distribution. So for each point, you can create a random number with the Poisson distribution. What happens when you get 2 or more? This method forces you to answer that question. Maybe you artificially clamp to one, maybe you move into the neighbouring slot. This method won't create exactly N points, so if you must have N, you can put in a fudge (randomly add/remove the last few points).